# UI-GRID Cell Contain Drop Down, Other Cell Contain Text Box

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Is it possible in UI-GRID to have a column that can contain a drop down in one CELL, while another row (CELL) contains a text box?

Does the entire column have to contain a drop down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in column definition:

```
{ name:'columnName',
 field:'age',
 width:150,
 cellTemplate: 
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><span>Age 2:{{COL_FIELD}}</span> 
    <div ng-if="COL_FIELD.someBoolenToCheckWhatToUse">
      <select>
         <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
         <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
   </div>'
   <div ng-if="!COL_FIELD.someBoolenToCheckWhatToUse">
       <input type="--" value="--">
   </div>' 
 }
}
```